# Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Contact: zak>]>": "Booking.contact" must be a "Contact" instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have an issue, I created a form where users can make a reservation (in detail view) of a unique product. So one user can have multiples booking. The form used contain email and username. This form is in my `detail.html` with include variable.

```
{% include 'store/list.html' with list_title=name %}
```

So, When I run my server, go to the reservation page, put an username, email and submit, I have an error instead to redirect to an another page.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
    class Contact(models.Model):
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Marque(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class Model(models.Model): #Plusieurs models pour une marque
        reference = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        picture = models.URLField()
        marque = models.ForeignKey(Marque, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Booking(models.Model): #plusieurs réservation pour un contact
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        contacted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        marque = models.OneToOneField(Marque, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        model = models.OneToOneField(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.contact.name
```

**views.py**:

```
   ...
def detail(request, model_id):
    model = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=model_id)
    #marques = [marque.name for marque in model.marque.all()]
    #marques_name = " ".join(marques)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        name = request.POST.get('name')

        contact = Contact.objects.filter(email=email)
        if not contact.exists():
            #If a contact is not registered, create a new one
            contact = Contact.objects.create(
                email = email,
                name = name
            )
        #If no album matches the id, it means the form must have been tweaked
        #So returning a 404 is the best solution
        model = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=model_id)
        booking = Booking.objects.create(
            contact = contact,
            model = model
        )

        #Make sure no one can book the model again
        model.available = False
        model.save()
        context = {
        'model_name': model.name
        }
        return render(request, 'store/merci.html', context)

    message = "Le model est {}. Conçu par la marque {}".format(model.name, model.marque)
    context = {
    "model_name" : model.name,
    "model_marque" : model.marque,
    "model_id": model.id,
    "thumbnail" : model.picture
    }

    return render(request, 'store/detail.html', context)
```

**search_form.html** inside of **detail.html**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 detail-separator">
    <form class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center" action="{% url 'store:search' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchForm">Chercher un Model</label>
        <input id="searchForm" class="form-control" name="query">
      </div>
      <span class="help-block" id="helpBlock">Trouvez le model de voiture de vos rêves !</span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what is your actual problem? What is happening in practice, and how does it differ from what you want? We do not have enough to go on here. Please think how you would explain this to a coworker who had offered to help you, and edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You contact query returns a queryset:

```
contact = Contact.objects.filter(email=email)
```

You then try to use `contact` as if it were a single `Contact` object:

```
booking = Booking.objects.create(
    contact = contact,
    model = model
)
```

This is why Django complains that it got a `Queryset` instead of a `Contact`.

You need to select one `Contact` even if the Queryset only contains one single object. E.g.

```
contacts = Contact.objects.filter(email=email)
if contacts.exists():
    contact = contacts[0]
else:
    #If a contact is not registered, create a new one
    contact = Contact.objects.create(
        email = email,
        name = name
    )
```

Or, preferably:

```
try:
    contact = Contact.objects.get(email=email)
except DoesNotExist:
    contact = Contact.objects.create(
        email = email,
        name = name
    )
```

Comment: Thanks but I have this error when I use (if, else) or (try, except): ERROR: A NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint in the column - « marque_id »

Comment: That's a different problem that likely happens when you try to create an instance of a model that has a foreign key to `Marque` without supplying a `Marque` instance. If you read the stack trace, you should find the line number where this happens.